# Spot light rendering in image, but not animation

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm rendering this simple rotating animation for a video essay; when I render it as an image it looks just like the viewport. But, when I render animation the spotlight doesn't render. The light is turned on in the outliner and I can't see anything in the render settings (using Eevee).

[image: My view]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Here's a drive link if that's okay https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oxVGckzafyhhebACeHPK0YPg9ai7P1pu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it seems to work fine for animation as well (as you didn't share the image it looks pink): https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/03/4c4n.jpg

Comment: This folder has the image, a rendered image and an image from animation render to show what I'm getting https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MGKB0Uc1MyDClm5L95f916lUrRgmk07g?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't download your files, I'm not sure why, could you please use another platform, like workupload for example?

Comment: Sure thing, here you go https://workupload.com/archive/SWEWzPuQSe

Comment: it still work fine, the light is very low though

Comment: I have no clue why, but I just deleted and added a new spotlight, pressed render and it works. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Oh ok great then  ;)  .............